# Load data from 2 tables and set second table data as subarray

Tags: php, pdo

Is it possible to load data from 2 tables using PDO and set second table data as subarray from first table? For example:

Tables :

```
article (id, title, description) 
links (id, article_id, link)
```

Loaded data ~ :

```
 stdClass Object
        (
            [article.id] => 1
            [article.title] => bla bla
            [article.description] => example description
            [article.links] => array (
              [0] => array (
               links.id => 1
               links.article_id => 1
               links.link => .......
              )
              [1] => array (
               links.id => 2
               links.article_id => 1
               links.link => .......
              )            
            )
          )
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how efficient this code would be, but you could use a combination of the [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and [concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) mysql functions to get the data into one row/column from the subquery, then you could bust it back out into an array in PHP.

```
select
    id,
    title,
    group_concat(concat(b.ID, '@@', b.link)) as linkies
from
    article a
        right outer join links b
            on b.article_id=a.ID
group by
    id,
    title
```

This will result in something like this coming back in your PDO results:

```
ID | Title   | linkies
1  | bla bla | 1@@yourLink, 2@@SomeOtherLink
2  | ble ble | 1@@yourLinkRow2, 2@@SomeOtherLinkAgain
```

Once in PHP, this would be fairily easy to bring back into arrays.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't get the result from PDO directly. You need to hydrate the objects yourself which is usually called object relation mapping.

Or you could try some ORM framework like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).